# How to elegantly distribute an Erlang release?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I have created my release.  The output is a fairly complicated directory structure, and many files.  It has a script that I can use to execute the program ('script start', 'script console', etc.)

How do I distribute this to customers?  Do I need to give them the entire directory structure?  Directory `bin`, with the script, is not at the top level which seems to imply that perhaps only it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to release it in production mode. $ rebar3 as prod release tar....

This will allow them to run ./bin/appname start from the top directory. You can also choose not to include source files by configuring your rebar.config file accordingly.

Comment: Can I ignore the other dirs, then?  lib, erts, etc?

Comment: lib includes dependencies that your app has, so what do you mean by ignore? You can select not to include source files by setting the include_src to false in profiles. When you create a release tar file it will have everything the machine will need to run your application, including the erlang vm.